# GRUB Failing to Boot to graphical interface

Tags: boot, grub2

First time install. Have attempted to install UBUNTU 14.04 server version from a USB key a couple of times now. After installation it would appear the Grub boot process fails and the screen goes into "Out of range" mode. I have read a few posts about this problem, have attempted to follow these recommendations, all without any success. Getting a little frustrated, that I appear to have installed everything, but the boot process is letting me down. What can I do to get a vanilla version of Ubuntu running with the LAMP stack? Are there alternatives to the GRUB boot loader, so I can get this install up and running?

Answer (score 0):

you can try boot repair, it resolves the out of range error. First try recommended repair, if still you get error then boot to live usb, then get the boot repair and then advanced options. Here you can select the out of range error check box.